# Attempt to present GameViewController on ViewController which is waiting for a delayed presention of <GKTurnVC> to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, modalviewcontroller

So on my turn based iOS game when I click "Find Game" it takes me to the correct view controller just not the current game joined e.g. so  if it was Naughts and Crosses, I am taken to the playing board but, can't actually take my turn because its taken me to the template not the current game joined. I believe it is due to this in the debug log:

```
Attempt to present <GameViewController: 0x790cb030> on <ViewController: 0x790bfe80> which is waiting for a delayed presention of <GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController: 0x7a88de00> to complete

Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <GameNavigationController: 0x790bfb20> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

The second line is when I attempt to use the back button, it takes me back to the main menu but then quickly returns to the GameViewController.

I think changing the following code is what will fix this problem, I just have no idea how. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
    [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [presentingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];


 [self dismissModalViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

When presenting view controllers you have to be careful that you have finished one before you start the other. The best way to do this if you think there may be an overlap is to use the completion handler like so:

```
[controller1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self presentViewController:controller2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}];
```

The code above dismisses the first visible view controller (e.g. a `UIAlertController`) and upon completion presents a new view controller.

An example of when you might come across this would be for a loading animation, perhaps you've presented a `UIAlertController` informing the user that a lengthy task is underway. When the task finishes you want to dismiss the `UIAlertController` and present a new custom view controller. This custom view controller must be presented in the completion handler. *See above*.

Comment: I don't understand present next controller here? I don't have another controller to present, just the current one (game joined).

Comment: In your code it looks like you're dismissing a view controller then attempting to perform a segue on the view controller you've just dismissed. Try omitting the line `[presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that. Log details:                                                                                                             `Attempt to present <GameViewController: 0x79a9d600> on <ViewController: 0x797315a0> which is waiting for a delayed presention of <GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController: 0x7bbc8000> to complete
Warning: Attempt to present <GameViewController: 0x79685190>  on <ViewController: 0x797315a0> which is already presenting (null)
Entering new game...`

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to present/dismiss view controllers more than one at a time. The 3 lines of code you've supplied suggest that 1) you're not waiting until one presentation is complete before starting another and 2) you're trying to present view controllers on other view controllers that are no longer in the hierarchy. More than this I cannot say from what you've given here.

Comment: I have searched my code and can't find anything else that would cause the problem. However, I did find by commenting out one line it fixed my back button issue.  This created another problem though, when hitting Find Game it doesn't show the matchmaking screen, just goes straight to the game template. The code in question: `[presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];`